# Wrapping my head (and this site) around responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive

So I have created a website from scratch just using pure HTML and CSS and sublime text, I created this site to be displayed on my portfolio to show potential employers. I am new in this field and I have not yet landed a job so I am giving myself personal projects to show off. Everything on the site is working correctly however now I want to make it mobile friendly.

I have added some break points already using the knowledge I acquired watching videos on the subject on Youtube. However how do I target every possible width and height of a given screen? For example at 320px wide it looks fine. I take away the image in the header and fix up the footer but as soon as I hit 321 px wide everything goes haywire. My question is how do I remedy that? what can I do in my media queries to target everything? Here is the code:

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
}
/*------------------Header Styling------------------*/
header {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
  font-family: "Freehand521 BT", Arial, Sans-serif;
}
header p {
  font-family: "Freehand521 BT", Arial, Sans-serif;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
header img {
  float: right;
  border-left: solid;
}
/*------------------Main Nav Styling------------------*/
#mainlinks {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
#mainlinks ul {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#mainlinks a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 90px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
#mainlinks a:hover {
  color: #D423A2;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#mainlinks li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
/*------------------Secondary Nav Styling------------------*/
.secondlinks li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.secondlinks ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.secondlinks a {
  margin-right: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.secondlinks a:hover {
  color: #7A0A56;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.7s;
}
.secondlinks a#moon:hover {
  color: #FFE619;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.7s;
}
.secondlinks a#mars:hover {
  color: #E30000;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.7s;
}
.secondlinks a#mercury:hover {
  color: #1BB9EB;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.7s;
}
.secondlinks a#jupiter:hover {
  color: #21EB47;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.7s;
}
.secondlinks a#venus:hover {
  color: #F7B20F;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.7s;
}
/*------------------Main Content Styling------------------*/
#contentwrap {
  background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, .7);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Freehand521 BT", Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#contentwrap img {
  border-style: solid;
}
.top {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.top :hover {
  color: #D423A2;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*------------------Footer Styling------------------*/
footer {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top-style: solid;
  margin-top: -130px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  font-family: "Freehand521 BT", Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}
#footernav {
  float: right;
}
#footernav li {
  display: inline;
}
#footernav a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
#footernav a:hover {
  color: #D423A2;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#copyright {
  position: absolute;
  left: 550px;
  bottom: 30px;
}
/*------------------Media Queries for Responsive Design------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width:960px) {
  #header {
    width: auto;
  }
  #contentwrap {
    width: auto;
  }
  #footer {
    width: auto;
  }
  #copyright {
    left: 300px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 812px) {
  header p {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  #copyright {
    left: 250px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  header p {
    font-size: 29px;
  }
  #mainlinks a{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  header img {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  #copyright {
    left: 100px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  #pharaoh_90_content img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #queen_nehelenia_content img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Defenders Of The Stars!--The Official Sailor Moon Fanpage!</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/SM.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <img src="images/HeaderSilouette.png" alt="Defenders Of The Stars Header" width="200" height="200">
  <p>Defenders of the stars!</p>
  <nav id="mainlinks">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="ss.html">Sailor Senshi</a></li>
      <li><a href="villains.html">Villains</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="contentwrap">
  <h1> Welcome Fans!</h1>
  <p>Welcome to the Official Sailor Moon Fanpage! Here you will find a lot of information about the Sailor Moon Universe! Including Characters and villains alike, As well as an overview of the story so far. We will also keep this Page updated with the latest happenings in the world of Sailor Moon!</p>
  <p><u>July 5 2014</u> - New Sailor Moon Anime, Sailor Moon Crystal is released!</p>
</div>
<footer>
  <p id ="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2016 Jorge Goris.<br />Designed and developed by Jorge Goris.</p>
  <nav id="footernav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="ss.html">Sailor Senshi</a></li>
      <li><a href="villains.html">Villains</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to talk more about what you have tried already and maybe narrow your question down a little.  You're asking too much in one question here.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to consider the design and elements of your website and decide what looks best on which screen size, which content to display and which to hide, etc.,. Then by using media queries, you can target every different screen size ranges and make changes to the styles applied on your elements to make the website responsive.

As for your saying that the website screws up after 321px - you need to define more media queries targeting different screen sizes beyond the range of 320px. Once you do that your website will look good, no matter which device it's viewed on.

Here is an article on standard media queries which will help you define the ranges:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/